# Sampling distributions help with questions

Tags: distributions, probability, self-study, sampling, mathematical-statistics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Probability of mean of random sample being in a certain range](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16552/probability-of-mean-of-random-sample-being-in-a-certain-range)

When a pizza restaurant’s delivery process is operating effectively, pizzas are delivered in an average of 45 minutes with a standard deviation of 6 minutes.  Suppose each night, 9 deliveries are selected at random and their delivery times are recorded.  For the sake of argument, assume that the pizza deliveries are normally distributed. (3 pts each)

1. What is the probability that the average time for the sample mean each night is within 2 minutes of the population mean?
2. What is the probability that the average time for the sample mean each night is within 2.5 minutes of the mean?
3. What is the probability that the average time for the sample mean is within 4 minutes of the mean?

I'm doing some research and teaching myself how to solve these, any help on the answers?

Comment: The duplicate asks the same thing as questions 1, 2, and 3, but with different numbers.

Comment: I don't see how it's solved the same way, but thanks for closing my question, really appreciate kind hearted people

Comment: You ought to take a quick look at the StackExchange intro pages and our own [faq], Franklin, because--taking your comment to be sardonic--it sounds like you have a misapprehension about what this site is. If the duplicate does not answer your question, at least having it pointed out that it *does* provide an answer should have advanced your research. I invite you now to modify your question to show where the disconnect is in your mind between the information in the duplicate and the information you are looking for: that may make your question both unique and helpful to you.