# Given a normal distribution, a mean, and standard deviation what is the probability a Variable is in a range

Tags: probability, self-study, normal-distribution

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Normal distribution probability](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5504/normal-distribution-probability)

Issues getting to the bottom of a HW problem, but I am not looking for the answer, just some guidance.

x has a normal distribution with 
   the specified mean = 15.9
   and standard deviation = 3.6

Find the indicated probability P(10 ≤ x ≤ 26)?

I assume i need to take the values 10 and 26 and calculate Z-Scores, and then go the Z-Score table and take the differences in the P-Values?  Is this the right approach or am I missing something?  I followed that reasoning and the answer was wrong - so either I made a rounding  mistake, or have chosen the wrong path.

Thank you for the advice in advance.

Comment: If you can get away from always thinking in terms of $p$ values and $z$ scores and R commands and want to learn how to _use_ tables of normal distribution probabilities (instead of just being told that the answers can be looked up in tables), [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/202612/15941) on math.SE might be useful.

Answer (score 2):

Am I missing something or is this basic probability calculus? for any r.v. $X$ with a known cumulative distribution function $F_X (x)$, $P(a<x\leq b) = F_X (b) - F_X (a)$.

Answer (score 1):

You need to perform transformation of the random variable with distribution 
$$
X \sim \mathcal{N}(a=15.9,b^2=3.6^2)
$$
to normal variable 
$$
Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)
$$

To do this use the formula: 
$$
P(X<m) = P( \frac{X-a}{b} < \frac{m-a}{b})=P(Z<\frac{m-a}{b})
$$

The idea is that the expression $$Z = \frac{X-a}{b} \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$$ has standard normal distribution.
Then you can use std. distribution table to get values of $$P(Z<\frac{m-a}{b})$$

Answer (score 0):

I redid the problem using R (I didn't know the pnorm function existed) as opposed to the Z-sore table and the process was correct (the correct answer was one hundredth off, so I must have made a typo).  I suppose I just assumed I did the problem wrong.

Comment: In R: pnorm(26, 15.9,3.6)-pnorm(10, 15.9,3.6)